# jQuery form validation not working

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

I'm struggling with my form validation here:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready( function() {

 $("#submit").click(function(){               

  // set initial error value to false
  var hasError = false;

  // set var for each form field
  var order_ref = $("#order_ref").val();
  var order_name = $("#order_name").val();
  var order_telephone = $("#order_telephone").val();
  var order_email = $("#order_email").val();
  var order_message = $("#order_message").val();
  var order_size = $("#sendEmail input.radio:checked").val();

  // validate each of them
  if(order_ref == '') { $("#order_ref").addClass('haserror'); hasError = true; } 
  if(order_name == '') { $("#order_name").addClass('haserror'); hasError = true; } 
  if(order_telephone == '') {  $("#order_telephone").addClass('haserror'); hasError = true; } 
  if(order_email == '') { $("#order_email").val().addClass('haserror'); hasError = true; } 
  //if(order_message == '') { $("#order_message").val().addClass('haserror'); hasError = true; } 
  if(order_size == '') { $("#order_size").val().addClass('haserror'); hasError = true; } 

  // if there are errors
  if(hasError == true) {
   alert('whoa!');
   return false;
  };

  // if there's no errors, proceed   
  if(hasError == false) {
   $.post("/photo/theme/foodphoto/includes/mail_send.php",
       { 
     // pass each of the form values to the PHP file for processing
     order_ref: order_ref, 
     order_name: order_name, 
     order_telephone: order_telephone, 
     order_email: order_email, 
     order_message: order_message,
     order_size: order_size
    },
        function(data){
      // no errors? great now do what you want to show the user his message is sent
      $('#sendEmail, .faded').slideUp(500);
      $('.thanks').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
        }
     );
  }; 

  return false;
 }); 

});
```

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are wrong:

```
if(order_email == '') { $("#order_email").val().addClass('haserror'); hasError = true; } 
if(order_size == '') { $("#order_size").val().addClass('haserror'); hasError = true; }
```

remove the val()

Copy/paste error it looks like :)

Comment: also, would be nice if `if(hasError == true){}` is just `if(hasError){}` and `if(hasError == false){}` is just `if(!hasError){}` ;)